# How to open .IBA file in my ipad application

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ibooks, ibook-author

How can i open `.iba` file in my `ipad,iphone application`?

I made `.iba` file from ibooks author. now i want to merge this file with my `ipad application`.

I try to find in google but i can't find proper solution or code.

Please give me any suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Did you ever get a reply to this?  You don't open an .iba file on the ipad.  It's the project file for ibooks author.  You have to generate an .ibooks file from ibooks author.  You can do that either via File > Export or Share > Export.  Just choose the ibooks option and save it on your computer.  I put mine in one of my web server folders and I then I access that folder via a url in safari on the ipad.  It'll automatically load it into the ibooks app for you.